# Who sent you?

Tags: php

I have a series of input forms, all of them take a different form action. Each of those validates input. If ok, they go to different success pages. If fail, I want the form action/validation pages to set $_SESSION['error_messages'] and go to a common page which displays the errors and has a "resubmit" button.

Question ... how to get error form the resubmit button back to one of many possible input forms?

---

Edit: I don't see how `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is going to work. Again: form --> validation --> error_page

So, I guess that `validation` has to set  a session variable from $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: Wait a minute... are all the forms present in the same page? I thought they are in different pages. Otherwise my answer is incorrect

Comment: +1 all forms are on different pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USing `HTTP_REFERER` is an option, but possibly not the most viable one, as the referrer header is easily spoofable (and not all the browsers will send it). This may or may not interfere with your process.

The easiest thing to do, as you are already setting error messages in `$_SESSION` is to also add a `$_SESSION['redirect_url']` value.

Comment: +1 but that requires adding a line of code - which could be forgotten

Comment: @Mawg: I'm sorry, but I really don't get your point... you're programming a website so, yes, you will have to add lines of code, I thought that was the whole point of it.

Comment: @Mawg, you could throw an error or exception if the $_SESSION['redirect_url']` value is not set while the form is being processed, so it will never be forgotten. @nico But I suggest posting the module name in a hidden field instead of session variable because I feel too many session variables can disorganize the project, specially of lots of people work, many leaving, many new joining, you may need to search the entire project where which session variable was set. Plus there can be name conflicts

Comment: @nico - From wikipedia "In the context of network security, a spoofing attack is a situation in which one person or program successfully masquerades as another by falsifying data and thereby gaining an illegitimate advantage." How will this allow a user to masquerade as another user?

Comment: @ andeepan +1  Yes, I agree, but you know how easy it is to forget one line and ... @$#%!!   I can encapsulate it in a function (and use __FILE__)

Comment: @Neal Donnan: that's not the only type of spoofing. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referrer_spoofing . I repeat, all of this may not apply here, we don't know what the form is doing, maybe it is fine to use HTTP_REFERER in this particular instance. However, relying on sessions is definitely more secure.

Comment: @Mawg: you can have a generic fallback message/URL that are used if you forgot to specify them.

Answer (score 2):

Using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

But, as per http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

> The address of the page (if any)
>   which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user
>   agent. Not all user agents will set
>   this, and some provide the ability to
>   modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In
>   short, it cannot really be trusted.

So, like Neal Donnan has suggested, passing the `module_name` in a hidden field and then resubmitting to `http://project/'.$_POST['module_name']` would be best

Comment: Or, if the http referers are being stripped from requests by a rather diligent security conscious user, by setting $_SESSION['error_return_path']?

Comment: +1 but I don't have control over the eventual IT guys & their settings

Comment: @Mawg: You don't need any control on server settings to use that.

Comment: @Ninefingers how exactly can HTTP_REFERER be spoofed? I am sure you know the answer

Comment: Well it's sent in the request from client to server. Therefore, like any part of the HTTP GET request, it can be changed. Give tamper data a go on Firefox. There isn't much you can't modify... it's just strings of data going down a cable. You create a security issue by relying on the referrer because an enterprising bad guy could redirect from the error message to *their* form. Not good if it's a user a reg form.

Comment: @Ninefingers thanks for the user form example. So, I understand that by editing the `HTTP_REFERER` and redirecting from the error messages, a bad guy can redirect to their form. But, will that happen only for that particular spoofing session? Or is it like if the spoofing is done on a public computer for a site, all users using that computer for that site will be redirected to the bad guy's user form?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HTTP_REFERER header, but this is not always reliable as the browser needs to set this.

A more reliable way would be to set a hidden field in each form with the url to redirect back to.

Comment: How is an hidden field more reliable? It is easier to spoof than `HTTP_REFERER`. Just open Firebug and you're done. Spoofing may or may not pose a problem here, but if your concerned about using `HTTP_REFERER` then you should definitely not use hidden fields.

Comment: @nico - I think you are getting confused with security here, that is a separate issue altogether. You can spoof anything from curl on the command line, this is where server side security comes in. It is more reliable because not all browsers will set the HTTP_REFERER, you can control setting the hidden field on the form though.

Comment: @nico Good point but of course ,I know that we can open firebug and change hidden values. I will put it in hidden field only if I am sure a spoofer does not gain anything by editing that. But, how exactly can  `HTTP_REFERER` be spoofed?

Comment: @sandeepan: HTTP_REFERER can be spoofed in a lot of ways, essentially by connecting to the site and specifying the headers (you can do that for instance using telnet or PHP). The easiest way, which requires 0 programming capabilities, is using FF extensions such as refspoof.

Comment: @nico thanks for the info. +1 to your answer too. I gained a lot of knowledge today regarding this!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're using the same script, if not *please* post your code:

Input page:

```
<?php
/* this is the form page header */

/* parsing & filtering input */

if( my_form_is_valid($input_data) )
   give_the_answer();
else
   header('Location:' . $_POST['request_uri'] . '&status=error');  //make sure that's the first output

/* follow the DOM */
?>

<form id="myform">
   <!-- some fields -->
   <input type="hidden" name="request_uri" id="request_uri" value=<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
</form>
```